# how to initialize weights for DNNClassifier in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to apply different activation functions for samely configured deep neural network models in TensorFlow. That's why, initial weights should be same for these classifiers. However, I cannot find a solution for this task. Should I clone first_classifier to second_classifier, or transfer first_classifier's weights to second classifier. Thank you for your support.

```
first_classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns = feature_columns
    , hidden_units = [3]
    , activation_fn = tf.nn.sigmoid
    , optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learningRate))

second_classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns = feature_columns
    , hidden_units = [3]
    , activation_fn = tf.nn.tanh
    , optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learningRate))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems from [DNN docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier#__init__) that you can't set initial weights directly; except using the `set_params` . Best way is to share the parameters (clone or transfer) between two classifiers.

Comment: do you have an idea how to clone / transfer between classifiers? I cannot find an example about using set_params function.

Comment: How about using checkpoints with `tf.train.Saver`, run one iteration in one network and the restore the checkpoint in the other. I think it might do the trick.